# jQuery slideDown not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown

I simply can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this really simple slideDown jQuery function. It's supposed to animate the appearance of a `div` when another `div` is clicked. But, when I click the firing `div`, nothing happens. Where is my mistake here?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#testdiv {background-color:#999900; height:100px; width:100px; display:none;}
</style>

<script src="/personal/xnb1159/Shared%20Documents/Test/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#test").click(function() {
    $("#testdiv").slideDown("fast",function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test">Click me.</div>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Script` needs to be underneath the `HTML`

Comment: ... or inside `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your jquery code in a document.ready so it runs when the elements are all loaded.

```
$(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    $("#testdiv").slideDown("fast",function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});
```

Or add your JS scrip at the end of your body tag.

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping in a `(document).ready()` worked. That was a simple fix.